# Sort DirectoryInfo by creation date

Tags: vb.net, sorting, .net

This code gives me the a list of folders. Without sorting it comes up oldest first. Although I don't think that could be guaranteed.(it could sort based on file name which is a date). I want to use the OrderBy or OrderByDescending function to sort it newest first based on the creation date.

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(root)
folderList = di.GetDirectories()

'does not work
folderList.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.CreationTime)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to (re)assign the value that `OrderByDescending` returns to the variable, it will not order the original collection.

For example:

```
folderList = folderList.
    OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.CreationTime).
    ToArray()
```

Another option is to sort the original array:

```
Array.Sort(folderList, Function(d1, d2) d1.CreationTime.CompareTo(d2.CreationTime))
```

I'm using [this overload of `Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx) with a `Comparison(Of T)`.